# How to write this using LINQ to SQL?

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

What is the equivalent of this SQL query in LINQ to SQL?

```
select *
from Leads, LeadCustomAttributes LCA  
where Leads.LeadID = LCA.LeadID  
&& LCA.AttributeID in ('2','4','2')
```

Answer (score 1):

```cs
var query =
    from lead in db.Leads
    from lca in db.LeadCustomAttributes
    where lead.LeadID == lca.LeadID
    where new[] { "2", "4" }.Contains(lca.AttributeID)
    select new { lead, lca };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] ids = { 2, 4, 2};

var result = from leads in context.Leads
             join LCA in context.LeadCustomAttributes
             ON leads.LeadID = LCA.LeadID
             Where ids.Contains(ids.ContainsLeadCustomAttributes)
             select leads;
```